# What is the 4th "level" of version number for the S. cerevisiae reference genome?

Tags: reference-genome, snpeff

yeastgenome.org has releases called R64-1-1, R64-2-1, etc, with 3 "levels" of versioning but in a few places I have seen a "fourth level". For example, Ensemble calls their hosted version of R64-1-1 "version 51" (http://ftp.ensemblgenomes.org/pub/fungi/release-51/fasta/saccharomyces_cerevisiae/dna/). And the pre-created databases available with snpEff 4.3 include "R64-1-1.75" and "R64-1-1.99". I assume the "75" and "99" here correspond to Ensembl's "51". What is this fourth number and what does it mean?